# How do I detect a subset of tags with regexp in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, tags

I want to detect, in a JavaScript String, if there are some tags except than a list that I have. It means if in my String there are undesirable tags, then I detect them.

What I have done is :

```
var expression = new RegExp("<[^(BR|SPAN|STRONG|STRIKE|EM|U|FONT)]*>", "gi");

if (expression.test(aString)) {
      // detection
}
```

But this regex does not seem to work..

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
var expression = new RegExp("<(BR|SPAN|STRONG|STRIKE|EM|U|FONT) ?[^>]*>", "gi");
```

... and reverse your test (i.e. if this tests *true* then the bad tags are found)

The `[^...]` solution you tried only works on *characters* and sets thereof, not on strings.

I'm ending with `[^>]*>` which means, "any amount of anything that isn't a `>`, followed by a `>`", so that you'll also catch elements with attributes.

**EDIT**

As MSalters pointed out, it seems I misread your question. You do not want to reverse the expression, but rather, you want to do something like this

```
var expression = new RegExp("<(?!BR|SPAN|STRONG|STRIKE|EM|U|FONT) ?[^>]*>", "gi");
```

If it tests *true* then your input contains tags that are not in the above list.

Comment: You are right, with the reverse of the test your solution is really good. Thanks a lot for this help ! Have a good day !

Comment: Ehm, it's a whitelist, and the test was already "reversed". With your idea, if I check `<SPAN><BadTag/>Random text</SPAN>`, the `<BR>` is matched and the test passes. The regex _has_ to detect the `<BadTag>` substring.

Comment: Now I'm trying to get my head wrapped around that one - `(?!)` is non-capturing. So, when matching `<BAD >`, the negative assertion passes, but the ` ?` is never going to consume the actual tag - that has to be eaten by `[^>]*`. So, what's the point of ` ?` there? I can only see it match `< >`, and even in that case the ` ?` is redundant.

Comment: @MSalters: bah, you're right, of course. That ` ?` is completely redundant, I didn't think that part through. Still, the above solution, stripping the redundant stuff if you will, would solve the problem, wouldn't it? Because I'd argue it's far more readable and extensible than the alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can invert the test that you want, but it's bloody hard.

What you want to find is roughly `<([^BSEUF].*|U[^ >]+|B|B[^R].*|BR[^ >]+|E|E[^M].*|EM[^ >]+|||||)` - I've left out the part that matches tags staring with S, but you should get the pattern. First I catch anything that doesn't start with B, S, E, U or F. Next I catch anything that starts with a U, but has extra characters following the U (eg. `<UA>`). The third case catches `<B>`. The 4th case catches `<BA>` and `<BAA>`. The 5th case catches `<E>`. The 6th case catches `<BRA>`. The 7th case catches `<EA>` and `<EAA>`, the 8th case catches `<EMA>`.

To finish this, you've got to catch `<SPA>`, `<SA>`, `<SPAA>`, `<SPANA>` etcetera: tags that differ because they're (1) to short, (2) different after a certain shared prefix, or (3) longer than an acceptable tag.

Comment: umm... what is there to this problem that we can't solve with negative lookahead?